# Can I use two Where in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I'm trying to get a date range and a transaction type in a query. I'm working in PHP with a Mysql database. 
Originally, the statement was

```
         ("select * from accounting WHERE date between '$startdate' AND 
        '$enddate'",$prop);
```

It works beautifully, no issues @ all. But I also need it to select a column in the database called transaction type. 
Here's how I modified it:

```
           ("SELECT date, account, description, Income FROM accounting where 
           transactiontype = 'Income' and WHERE date between '$startdate' AND 
           '$enddate' order by date ASC",$prop);
```

I'm getting the error message:
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE date between '2012/09/01' AND '2013/04/17' order by date ASC' at line 1
Query: SELECT date, account, description, Income FROM accounting where transactiontype = 'Income' and WHERE date between '2012/09/01' AND '2013/04/17' order by date ASC
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Drop the second where.  (PS: I didn't down vote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND is enough, you don't need the seconde WHERE.

```
("SELECT `date`, account, description, Income 
  FROM accounting 
  WHERE transactiontype = 'Income' 
  AND `date` between '$startdate' 
  AND '$enddate' order by `date` ASC",$prop);
```

By the way, try to avoid reserved keywords as table / columns name (like date).
You'll have to escape them all the time (and will forget that all the time also).

Comment: That Works! Thank you for your prompt help!

Answer (score 0):

```
("SELECT date, account, description, Income FROM accounting where 
  transactiontype = 'Income' and "date" between '$startdate' AND 
 '$enddate' order by date ASC",$prop);
```

You may also need to enclose the date in speech marks or ticks (`), as indicated.

Comment: Yep - I'll bow to your knowledge with that one!  ;o)

Answer (score 0):

kindly remove the second where clause..

```
       (SELECT date, account, description, Income FROM accounting where 
       transactiontype = 'Income' and (date between '$startdate' AND 
       '$enddate') order by date ASC",$prop )
```